# If Condition for multiple values

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I have a dropdown list where i have list of values from 0 TO 9

If the selected value is 1,2,3,4 or 5 then EmployeeName field cannot be blank.

Please help me to write this condition in vb.net.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you have OR operators in vb.net ?

Comment: @THE NEW IDiot I am new to vb.net and programming too.I know  OR operator should be use, but i am not aware that how to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can string multiple conditions together in one, such that:

```
If (thing = 1 OrElse thing = 2 OrElse thing = 3 OrElse thing = 4 OrElse thing = 5) 

End IF
```

However, you could add these values to a whitelist, and do an `Any` or `Contains` check. You could of course to a *lower than* and *greater than* comparison to constrain, but I didn't risk that without enough detail.

Answer (score 6):

I think your best bet is to use a `Select` statement. This makes it easy to maintain your code if you change what each value does:

```
Select Case CInt(ComboBox.Value)

Case 1 To 5
    'Employee field cannot be blank
Case Else
    'Employee field can be blank
End Select
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if SelectedValue <= 5 And SelectedValue >= 1 then
' EmployeeName cannot be blank
```